# I don't wanna indexing DynamoDB secondary indexes in Elasticsearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have one DynamoDB table, and there is a secondary index on the table.

But I have a faced duplication problem when I was query something.

I don't want my Lambda function don't trace secondary index...

I saw IAM policy but there is no relational policy.

How can I solve this problem? This is my lambda function: [aws-dynamodb-to-elasticsearch/dynamodb-to-es.py at master · vladhoncharenko/aws-dynamodb-to-elasticsearch](https://github.com/vladhoncharenko/aws-dynamodb-to-elasticsearch/blob/master/scripts/dynamodb-to-es.py)

Comment: Sorry not to describe well... I'm using elastic-search indexing aws dynamoDB table! And I used Lambda Function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because you have many Lambda functions or many Lambda Function versions in your account for that region.

```
[Total size of all the deployment packages that can be uploaded per region | 75 GB][1]
```

Looks like this is a [pretty common problem](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/400) for `serverless` and someone has developed a plugin to help alleviate this issue: https://github.com/claygregory/serverless-prune-plugin

If you want to deal with this manually you'll need to use either the console, or an sdk/cli to delete old lambda versions. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/delete-function.html